# Error occurred while trying to proxy request SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN https api angular CLI

Tags: angular, https, proxy, certificate, signed

In IBM WAS and all we have an option to add the certificate to truststore, to get rid of such certificate issues. What we should do with npm ?

Answer (score 4):

The CLI is just a local proxy for development. You can add `"secure": false` to prevent the error.

Example:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Robin, here our api is in our existing spring API running in IBM was server, which is set to run only in https. http calls works like a charm and no issue is faced in that. Making it work with https is the prob here.

Comment: AFAIK as I know https won't be a problem. The secure false flag accept a self signed certificate.